# Reducing the run time

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I have a conceptual question.

Suppose I have a procedure (any language) which takes a data set as input, process it and write output to an array. This array is used down the stream for further processing. The problem is that code has large run time. So large that it needs to be optimized!

What I am proposing is to partition the input data set into smaller chunks and call the procedure for each of the data set in parallel. Sounds simple!

Hence I thought to write the procedure in a separate file, create a separate executable. Submit this executable for smaller data sets for batch processing.

But the problem with this method is that since each of the batch job is a separate process, how to create the array that I was creating earlier from all of these jobs! I can think of writing each job output to files and then process them to create the array back.

Is there a better way to do things in parallel?

Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: You are describing [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_Reduce).

Comment: Thanks for informing about it. I dont know anything about it. Any ideal if its freely available and if its going to be a lot of work using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it looks like MapReduce.

You might like to look at Erlang, which supports very elegant ways of partitioning and distributing work across processes, processors, and machines.

Joe Armstrong's Erlang book "Programming Erlang - Software for a Concurrent World" gives a simplistic MapReduce which can be used across processes.

I found these blogs which talk about Joe's simple MapReduce: 

http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070520.html

http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070601.html

which might explain the idea, and gives Erlang code.

Erlang is Open Source, so you could do a few experiments for a small investment in time.
Concurrency and communication are built into the language, and it all works 'out of the box' on a single machine. You do need to set up a 'key' so that Erlang Virtual Machines can commun icate, but once that's done, A program can be run across a local area network.

Answer (score 1):

As Oli said investigating MapReduce solutions available for your language is a good thing. The concrete way of doing really depends on your problem in both its theoretical and technical dimensions.

Here are some of the questions your might consider to answer : Can you have a distributed algorithm (no center node) ? Can we use a center node to synchronise computations (in a database for example) ? Does the batch processing time is small enough to consider file io as something long ? If yes, what kind of network layer can we use ? Are we running on a single computer and having some needs for IPC ?

Comment: I think for now I can go with a simpler solution since my program execution time is way more than file I/O time. Hence I can write all the data in files and later merge the data by file processing. I don't exactly have a distributed algorithm. Its just the sequential algorithm which you run on multiple input data sets by submitting jobs to different servers.

Comment: This is a kind of distributed algorithm. If your code isn't multithreaded maybe you could consider running multiple instances of your program per computer to use all the availables CPU.

Comment: yes this is what I will do...and once all the computations are done across all CPUs I will merge all generated files :-)